# What am I doing wrong with this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, denormalization

Good evening, I'm currently working on an SQL case study that involves solving this problem.

What is the total quantity of each ingredient used in all delivered pizzas sorted by most frequent first?

The plan is to create a query with a case statement for each topping. If a pizza has an extra topping it will count as 2 for the corresponding topping column.

Table with the pizza_id's and their corresponding toppings

| pizza_id | toppings |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10 |
| 2 | 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12 |

Pizza_toppings

| topping_id | topping_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bacon |
| 2 | BBQ Sauce |
| 3 | Beef |
| 4 | Cheese |
| 5 | Chicken |
| 6 | Mushrooms |
| 7 | Onions |
| 8 | Pepperoni |
| 9 | Peppers |
| 10 | Salami |
| 11 | Tomatoes |
| 12 | Tomato Sauce |

When I apply the query below

```
 ;with ingredient_cte as (
 select c.order_id, c.pizza_id, exclusions, extras,
 case
     when c.pizza_id = 1 then 1
     when extras in ('1', '1', '1, 4') then 2
     else 0 
 end bacon,
 case
     when c.pizza_id = 1 or c.order_id != 10 and exclusions != '2, 6' then 1
     else 0
 end bbq_sauce,
 case
     when c.pizza_id = 1 then 1
     else 0 
 end beef,
 case
     when c.pizza_id in (1, 2) or exclusions != '4' then 1
     else 0
 end cheese
 from customer_orders c
 join runner_orders r
     on c.order_id = r.order_id
join pizza_names n
     on c.pizza_id = n.pizza_id
where cancellation is null
)
select *
from ingredient_cte
```

I get this table

| order_id | pizza_id | exclusions | extras | bacon | bbq_sauce | beef | cheese |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | NULL | NULL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | NULL | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | NULL | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 | 2, 6 | 1, 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

The problem with my query is that it's returning some incorrect responses from some of my case statements, e.g. The bacon column in the last row be 2 since it includes extra bacon (1, 4). Also, the bacon row for order_id 5 should also be 2 which is why I used when extras in ('1', '1', '1, 4') then 2 as part of my query.

Comment: What's the name of the table that stores toppings? Is it really just 2 columns? What data type is `toppings`? Is it a csv of topping ids? If not, please clarify.

Comment: This is a **broken** schema design. It's **NEVER** good to store comma-separated data in a column, at least not if you want to query it in a way that performs at all well.

Answer (score -3):

To fix my query, I had to rearrange the structure of the case statement by starting with the conditions involving extra toppings (extras) and or excluded toppings (exclusions) before creating the condition for the toppings and their corresponding pizza, e.g. Bacon goes with Meatlovers aka pizza_id 1. I hope my updated explanation makes sense and sorry for wasting your time.

```
;with ingredient_cte as ( select c.order_id, customer_id, 
c.pizza_id, exclusions, extras,
case
    when extras = '1' then 2
    when extras = '1, 4' then 2
    when c.pizza_id = 1 then 1
    else 0 
end bacon,
case
    when exclusions = '2, 6' then 0
    when c.pizza_id = 1 then 1
    else 0 
end bbq_sauce,
case
    when c.pizza_id = 1 then 1
    else 0 
end beef,
case
    when exclusions = '4' then 0
    when extras = '1, 4' then 2
    when c.pizza_id in (1, 2) then 1
end cheese,
case
    when c.pizza_id = 1 then 1
    else 0 
end chicken,
case
    when exclusions = '2, 6' then 0
    when c.pizza_id = 2 then 1
    else 0
end mushrooms,
case
    when c.pizza_id = 2 then 1
    else 0 
end onions,
case
    when c.pizza_id = 1 then 1
    else 0
end pepperoni,
case
    when c.pizza_id = 2 then 1
    else 0
end peppers,
case
    when c.pizza_id = 1 then 1
    else 0 
end salami,
case
    when c.pizza_id = 2 then 1
    else 0
end tomatoes,
    case
    when  c.pizza_id = 2 then 1
    else 0
end tomato_sauce
from customer_orders c
join runner_orders r
    on c.order_id = r.order_id
join pizza_names n
    on c.pizza_id = n.pizza_id
where cancellation is null
)
select sum(bacon) bacon, sum(cheese) cheese, sum(beef) beef, 
sum(chicken) chicken, sum(pepperoni) pepperoni, 
sum(salami) salami, sum(bbq_sauce) bbq_sauce, sum(mushrooms) 
mushrooms, sum(onions) onions, sum(peppers) peppers, 
sum(tomatoes) tomatoes, sum(tomato_sauce) tomato_sauce
from ingredient_cte
```

Comment: This is not useful to anybody as an answer, because your question is only partially descirbed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).